# Correct join method for mysql tables in current case

Tags: mysql, join

I'm trying to figure it out what is the correct join method for my case of joining tables. I have following tables

I have a table users

```
id_user   name
  1       Mark
  2       Tesla
  3       Nick
```

and i have table orders

```
id_order  id_user
  1         1
  2         2
  3         1
  4         1
```

My problem is that i have to select user and join table orders,  so when i query one user i also have to see all of his orders. My current code selects only one order of particular user

```
SELECT * FROM users AS u
JOIN orders AS o
ON o.id_user = u.id_user
WHERE u.id_user = 1
```

I'm doing this completely wrong way? By the way i will use this code with PHP, so i can provide a object of user with all orders, when getting one user, if that information matters at all. If you need any additional information's please let me know and i will provide. Thank you in advance.

Comment: It returns all the orders: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f9bae3/1

Comment: My guess is the problem is in your PHP code, not SQL. I suspect you're not fetching all the rows of results.

Comment: hmmmm, the problem is that i get only first oreder ID not all orders from particular user

Comment: @Barmar, I missed that, sorry.

Comment: @Valor_, post your relevant PHP code snippet.

Comment: OMG, i'm sorry to even bother u guys. Yes the problem is in PHP code not mysql. I creating object completely wrong way. I will post answer later today. Thank you again!

Comment: or update answer if i will be unsuccessful :D Thank you again for now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you are looking for this..

```
SELECT orders.id_order, users.name FROM orders
INNER JOIN users
ON orders.id_user=users.id_user 
WHERE users.id_user = 1;
```